# Pass an additional command after ProcessBuilder starts

Tags: java

I have a Process created with ProcessBuilder.  It basically is wrapping a keytool command: https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/627.html

after I call `processBuilder.start()`, normally my keytool command would ask for the password.  How do I input my password after I run processBuilder.start()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to access the process IO streams, the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) shows that the methods you want to use are:

- `getOutputStream()` for the process `System.in`
- `getInputStream()` for the process `System.out`
- `getErrorStream()` for the process `System.err`

You will want to wrap the input and error streams in [Scanners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read lines from them, and the output stream in a [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) so you can print to it in a similar way to `System.out`.

You can read in the request for the password, and then print the password out to the process.